# How can I mention someone in an embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to @user and the bot will send an embed with the user I tagged

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content === ".help"){
        let user = message.mentions.users.first(); 
        const boopembed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('BB250C')
            .setTitle(':p')
            .setDescription(user)
        message.channel.send({embed: boopembed})      
    }
})
```

but every time I tag the user it doesn't send an embed or anything. But when I just do `.help` it sends everything.

Answer (score 0):

`.setDescription()` requires the parameter to be a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

So instead of doing `.setDescription(user)`, you could do something like:

```js
.setDescription(`<@${user.id}>`)
```

Comment: This works, but wouldn't it be cleaner to use `.setDescription(f"{user.mention}")` ?

Comment: @troll3rsk8tr That returns an error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Using Node.js v16. There is no such thing as `f"{user.mention}"` in javascript ([Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#template_literals)). If there is, I would like to read some articles about it.

Comment: Sounds like python f-strings to me.